# Remove numbers except that are before the first underscores in R with gsub

Tags: regex, gsub

I have this list:

l <- c("F1_6346346346_TrainTest_53453465.rds",    "F1_64575687357_FunctionTest_747434534.rds", "F3F4_546345647678_TrainTest_453463654.rds"

I would like to have somethins like this:

l <- c("F1_TrainTest", "F1_FunctionTest", "F3F4_TrainTest")

I have tried with 'gsub', but I am dummy with regular expressions and I haven`t been able to achieve this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/znKZoF/2)

```
(_(\d)+(\.rds)*)
```

replace with nothing, yields:

```
l <- c("F1_TrainTest", "F1_FunctionTest", "F3F4_TrainTest"
```

Get all groups of digits that may optionally be followed by .rds

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution hase been very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
_+\d+_*
```

- `_` - Matches `_` one or more time.
- `\d+` - Matches digits `0 to 9` one or more time.
- `-*` - Matches `_` zero or more time.

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/OzhJAp/2/)